# Flutter TextFormField hint text vertical align

Tags: flutter, textformfield

I'm using a custom hintText style, but I'm experiencing an alignment problem, as you can see below.

'Time' is not centered.

[image]

[image]
This is just normal hinttext Style

here is my code :

```
Container(
  width: 60,
  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12),
  child: const BasicTextFormField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      counterText: '',
      hintText: 'Time',
      hintStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 12,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
        color: Colors.grey,
      ),
      border: InputBorder.none, // Remove the underline
    ),
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  ),
),
```

I don't know why.

Comment: Just try wrapping the Container with Center widget. That should work.

Comment: Tried the code, Looks finely vertically centered by itself. It's parent or other widgets may be affecting it. Can you post a MRE?

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(
  width: 60,
  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12),
  child: const BasicTextFormField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      counterText: '',
      hintText: 'Time',
      hintStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 12,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
        color: Colors.grey,
      ),
      border: InputBorder.none, // Remove the underline
    ),
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  ),
),
```